# Two way binding when setter is overriden

Tags: cocoa, properties, key-value-observing

I have an NSTextField bound to some object "zoom" property.

In this object's class implementation, I have the following

```
- (void)setZoom:(CGFloat)zoom
{
    _zoom = MAX(0, MIN(10, zoom));
}
```

If I write "-5" in the textfield, `setZoom:` will be called with "-5" as argument and _zoom will be set to 0.

Then problem is that the textfield is not updating itself and it shows "-5" instead of re-reading the property value it has just set.

If I do `myObject.zoom = -5;` in code, the text field will display 0 correctly.

I tried to wrap _zoom =... inside willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey calls but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do in such way:

```
- (void)setZoom:(CGFloat)zoom
{
    CGFloat corectedValue = MAX(0, MIN(10, zoom));
    if (zoom != corectedValue)
    {
        [self setZoom:correctedValue];
    } else {
        _zoom = zoom;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same as wrapping _zoom =... with willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey calls. Which means it doesn't work.